# DataTable.Compute not working

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

Am using `DataTable.Compute()` method , but getting

> " Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column
>   argument with possible 'Child' qualifier. "

My Code :

```
  int x = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet1.Tables[0].
       Compute("SUM(Convert([qty],'System.Int32'))","[code] = 'ABC'"));
```

Here code is column of datatable and am reading the sum of qty. But I think the error might be because of qty is of type `string` and not able to convert into int type, but not sure.

Looking forward for answer and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It better to give try to linq by doing like this

```
int quantitysum= dt.Rows.Where(dr=>((string)dr["code"]) == "ABC") 
                             .Select(dr=>(int)dr["qty"]).Sum();
```

Comment: thnx.. I used : int quantitysum = dt.Select().AsEnumerable().Where(dr => ((string)dr["code"]) == "ABC").Select(dr => (int)dr["qty"]).Sum();

Answer (score 2):

Vinod don't compare your qty with `System.Int32`. Just write

```
Object Result = DataSet1.Table[0].Compute("SUM(qty)","code = 'ABC'");
```

and then you can use `Object` after casting to `integer`.